# Two JPanels in one JFrame - the second overrides the first

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I am trying to create a GUI where I add two JPanels to one JFrame, but the second JPanel I add override the first. In my first JPanel I have a sudoku box, and in the second I want a button. But, since the first one I add always overrides the second, this doesn't work.

My sudoku JPanel uses GridLayout, and this alone works perfectly. The problem is when I try to add the second JPanel (which has a JButton). Since the button needs to be another size than the squares in the sudoku box, I can't add this button to the first JPanel.

Is it possible to solve this using two JPanels, or do I need a different layout? I have read some about GridBagLayout and think this might be a solution, but it's a bit boring to change the whole code for my JPanel which has the sudoku in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make another JPanel with an appropriate layout manager, and add the two smaller panels inside it. Having panels inside of panels is a good way to break up your layout into less complex pieces while maintaining better control of resize behavior, etc.

Comment: This worked, but now the second panel is to the right of the first. I tried setting the first to center, and the second to south (borderlayout), but that didn't work. How do I get dem below each other?

Comment: Since you're doing border layout, have you tried setting the top one to NORTH, and the bottom one to SOUTH? You may be better off with a grid layout for the toplevel panel (1 col x 2 row).

Comment: BoxLayout worked perfectly, thank you for the help! :)